# C++: Convenient pointer array based value iterator for super-heavy objects

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, copying

In my code, I have something like this:

```
vector<SuperHeavyObject> objects; // objects in this vector are extremely slow to copy!
for (auto &objectGroup : objectGroups) {
    vector<SuperHeavyObject> objectsInThisGroup;
    for (size_t index : objectGroup) {
        objectsInThisGroup.push_back(objects[index]); // slow as copying is needed!
    }
    doSomething(objectsInThisGroup.begin(), objectsInThisGroup.end());
}
```

What I'd really want is something like this:

```
vector<SuperHeavyObject> objects; // objects in this vector are extremely slow to copy!
for (auto &objectGroup : objectGroups) {
    vector<SuperHeavyObject*> objectsInThisGroup; // pointers!
    for (size_t index : objectGroup) {
        objectsInThisGroup.push_back(&objects[index]); // not slow anymore
    }
    doSomething(magicIterator(objectsInThisGroup.begin()), 
                magicIterator(objectsInThisGroup.end()));
}
```

`doSomething` is allowed to copy the objects, so there's no scope problem. Inside `doSomething` is the only place where I'd like copying to take place, because these objects really are very slow to copy (I've profiled and it's a chokepoint).

At the same time, I don't want to change the signature of `doSomething` to accept iterators that dereference `SuperHeavyObject*`, because that would require a lot of changes; dereferencing to `SuperHeavyObject` would be ideal, as it would only happen at one place (where copying happens).

My question is; I could write an iterator like this myself, but it feels like I'm reinventing the wheel. Does C++ (11) have facilities to do this? I also have Boost if someone knows of anything like this.

Comment: Probably better lookup for something like `vector<std::shared_ptr<SuperHeavyObject>>`. Iteratior implementation sounds like the wrong tree you're barking up.

Comment: This is a well-worded, answerable question looking for a standard-provided solution to a legitimate requirement, I really cannot understand both the downvotes and the close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a legitimate use case for `std::reference_wrapper`<sup>1</sup>:

```
vector<SuperHeavyObject> objects;
for (auto &objectGroup : objectGroups) {
    vector<std::reference_wrapper<SuperHeavyObject>> objectsInThisGroup;
    for (size_t index : objectGroup) {
        // fast, we are only storing reference-like objects
        objectsInThisGroup.push_back(objects[index]);
    }
    doSomething(objectsInThisGroup.begin(), objectsInThisGroup.end());
}
```

---

1. C++11 required

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @matteo-italia for your helpful answer! I used it for a while, and decided to look closer at Boost's iterators, and I found that they have an `indirect_iterator` which is also a good way to do what I want.

"indirect_iterator adapts an iterator by applying an extra dereference inside of operator*()"

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/iterator/doc/indirect_iterator.html